PostgreSQL Jsonb error column tenantId does not exists
I have a jsonb column and I want to select some datas where tenant_id = ... but I got this error:
column tenant_id does not exists.

here is my code:
SELECT
raw_user_meta_data
FROM auth.users
WHERE raw_app_meta_data->'tenantId'::text = "tenant_id"
LIMIT 5;

edit:
this works when I only use numbers
SELECT
raw_user_meta_data
FROM auth.users
WHERE raw_app_meta_data -> 'tenantId' = '1233212112'
LIMIT 5;

when I use it with letters it is not working:
SELECT
raw_user_meta_data
FROM auth.users
WHERE raw_app_meta_data -> 'tenantId' = '1233212112cxy3'
LIMIT 5;


Double quotes " are for identifiers. The value on the right should use single quotes ' like the one on the left, if it's a constant.

@Zegarek then I get this error: Operaion does not exists jsonb = text, no operator matches the given name...

-> returns jsonb but ->> returns text
